# org-mode emacs won't export

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

I admit I'm a total emacs and org-mode newbie.
It worked great for me, but suddenly I'm having the following problem.

Say I open a file test.org with emacs

$ emacs test.org

The file contains:

```
* one
* two
** a
** b
```

When I try to export with 
C-x C-e 
I get the following error message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable b)
  eval(b nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

I just found out about org-mode and was immediately ecstatic about it.
Within minutes I could refactor my plain text notes for org-mode, including math formulas and export them to latex and from there pdf. I used C-x C-e o as explained here: http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX_002fPDF-export-commands.html

This worked great on both the GNU Emacs 23.3.1 that I have on my Mac OS X Terminal as well as with the newest Emacs release 24.1 which I had installed as a standalone .app

Unfortunately this didn't last very long and I got the error message described above, even for the most simple org files. What strikes me, that both installations of emacs started having this problem at the same time. I even deleted my, slightly modified, .emacs file in the home directory but that didn't help either.

It seems like emacs always fails wie evaluating the last line. If I delete it

```
* one
* two
** a
```

The error message is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable a)
  eval(a)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Any help is very much appreciated! I very much like org-mode and would love to learn el. However, at the moment I don't even know how to write more than two lines of LISP. Googling for this error message leaded to descriptions of problems that seemed to be totally unrelated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>C-c C-e h</kbd> (you indicate you are pressing <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>) to export to HTML and <kbd>C-c C-e p</kbd> to export to PDF. If you are using a menu bar, take a look under the "Org" menu, item "Export/Publish...(C-c C-e)"

(<kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> evaluates an elisp expression...those error messages are complaining about evaluation of **a and **b as elisp expressions...)

Comment: Not at all - the key bindings can get confusing at first. I agree with flaneur: using explicit commands might serve well, too.

Comment: That one drove me nuts! Thank you very much :) Was too tired to figure out that I wasn't hitting `C-c C-e` but `C-x C-e` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `M-x` and invoke the output method for the buffer using the interactive function name that matches the style you want, e.g.

```
M-x org-export-as-html
M-x org-export-as-pdf
M-x org-export-as-latex
```

etc.  Use tab to auto-complete the names. You may find this method simpler to remember while still learning your way around org-mode.